# for loop value semantic in golang

Tags: go

First question about Go in SO. The code below shows, n has the same address in each iteration. I am aware that such a for loop is called value semantic by some people and what's actually ranged over is a copy of the slice not the actual slice itself. Why does n in each iteration has the same address? Is it because each element in the slice is copied rather than the whole slice is copied once beforehand. If only each element from the original slice is copied, then a single memory address can be reused in each iteration?

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    numbers := []int{1, 2}
    for i, n := range numbers {
        fmt.Println(&n, &numbers[i])
    }
}
```

A sample result from go playground:

```
0xc000122030 0xc000122020
0xc000122030 0xc000122028
```

Comment: "Why does n in each iteration has the same address?" Thats how the language works. You have two variables i and n and both change their _value_ (not their identity) on each iteration. Unrelated to slice or whatever you range over.

Comment: `&n` is the address of the local loop variable `n`, which doesn't change with each iteration. It is *not* the address of the element in the slice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are slightly wrong in your question, it is not a copy of the slice that is being iterated over. In Go when you pass a slice you really pass a pointer to memory and the size and capacity of that memory, this is called a slice header. The header is copied, but the copy points to the same underlying memory, meaning that when you pass a `[]int` to a function, change the values in that function, the values will be changed in the original `[]int` in the outer code as well.

This is in contrast to an array like `[5]int` which is passed by value, meaninig this would really be copied when you pass it around. In Go structs, strings, numbers and arrays are passed by value. Slices are really also passed by value but as described above, the **value** in this case contains a **pointer** to memory. Passing a copy of a pointer still lets you change the memory pointed to.

Now to your experiment:

`for i, n := range numbers`

will create two variables before the loop starts: integers `i` and `n`. In each loop iteration `i` will be incremented by 1 and `n` will be assigned the value (a copy of the integer value that is) of `numbers[i]`.

This means there really are only two variables `i` and `n`. They are **the same** which is what you see in your output.

The addresses of `numbers[i]` are different of course, they are the memory addresses of the items in the array.

Comment: "**it is not a copy of the slice that is being iterated over**".  I think this is true in the sense that the question was asking about, but in a more literal sense the "slice" (often called the "slice header") seems to be copied upon the start of iteration: https://play.golang.org/p/HtW7-AsqWvO

Comment: Another experiment https://play.golang.org/p/kSpuGbj5Tyh

Comment: ok this confirms my thought and answered the question. I was slightly confused because in a go tutorial, the author said the whole slice is copied before the loop starts and then I saw each `n` has the same address which means it's can't be the whole slice is copied.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco hmm it's interesting to see two experiments, which also counters my updated thinking :D So it's not that each element from the slice is copied as the iteration goes; the slice was copied before the iteration starts?

Comment: Remember that a "slice" doesn't hold any data, it just points to an array that exists *somewhere*.  So when iteration starts, the for range loop crates a hidden copy of the slice, i.e, a pointer to where the real array is which holds the data, plus the length (and capacity) of the array.  This is why in the experiment, the for loop goes through all 10 elements even though the `slice` variable was re-sliced to only half the size while the loop was still going.

Comment: In the second experiment you can see that the main loop observed everything getting set to 0, but it didn't observe everything getting 100 added.  This is because when the `append` happened, `slice` was updated to point to a new, bigger array.  But the for loop still retains a pointer to the original array, so it still only sees the old array that was filled with zeros.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco thanks! I think your comments are the most useful info I got from this question.

Answer (score 1):

The Go Wiki has a [Common Mistakes page](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-reference-to-loop-iterator-variable) talking about this exact issue. It also provides an explanation of how to avoid this issue in real code. The quick answer is that this is done for efficiency, and has little to do with the slice. `n` is a single variable / memory location that gets assigned a new value on each iteration.

If you want additional insight into why this happens under the hood, take a look [at this post](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2019/go-internals-capturing-loop-variables-in-closures/).